# Python list input searching

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have this:

```
 [[(1, 'a')], [(2, 'b'), (2, 'c')], [(3, 'd'), (3, 'e')]]
```

I want to make an input to search for a/b/c/d/e and output the index of this letter.

E.g when searching `a -> index=0`,      `b and c -> index=1`,      `d and e -> index=2`

How is this possible on Python 3.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to iterate over the list first, then for each list obtained, iterate over it to get tuples.

```
>>> my_list = [[(1, 'a')], [(2, 'b'), (2, 'c')], [(3, 'd'), (3, 'e')]]
>>> 
>>> def search(val):
        for index, inner_list in enumerate(my_list):
            for nested_tuple in inner_list:
                if val in nested_tuple:
                    return index


>>> search('a')
0
>>> search('c')
1
>>> search('e')
2
```

Comment: You're not always searching for 'a', so let's make it a proper function.

Comment: Except for that there's a mistake now. ;)

Comment: @tvdien.. Ah! passing the list?

Comment: This doesn't give the correct output. It gives the index in the inner list, questioner wants the index of the inner list.

Comment: @Tim. Oh! little modification needed. On my way.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [dict comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) to make a mapping from letters to index:

```
 data = [[(1, 'a')], [(2, 'b'), (2, 'c')], [(3, 'd'), (3, 'e')]]    
 mapping = {key:index for index, items in enumerate(data) for num, key in items}
 print(mapping)
```

yields

```
{'a': 0, 'c': 1, 'b': 1, 'e': 2, 'd': 2}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a nested loop:

```
def find_index (data, key):
    for i, d in enumerate (data):
        for t in d:
            if t[1] == key:
                return i
```

This will return (by default) None when the key is not found.

Comment: Not very Pythonic to do a `for i in range(len(data))`. Rather use `enumerate()`.

Comment: I didn't know about that, thanks. I changed it now. It's much nicer indeed.

Answer (score 0):

```
     python 3.2
     lis= [[(1, 'a')], [(2, 'b'), (2, 'c')], [(3, 'd'), (3, 'e')]]


     # method 1. list comprehension
     >>> [i for i,v in enumerate(lis)for g in v if "a" in g]

     # method 2. loop

       def search(x):
            for i,v in enumerate(lis):
                 for k in v:
                       if x in k: return i
```